# How do I transfer files using SSH and SCP using Ruby calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a file in the directory `usr/share/ruby.rb`. I want to transfer that file to IP-based remote devices using SSH and SCP using Ruby calls. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5644110/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 22):

example:

```
require 'net/scp'

    host = '10.10.10.10'
    login = 'foo'
    password = 'bar'

    Net::SCP.start(host, login, :password => password) do |scp|
      puts 'SCP Started!'
      scp.download('/usr/share/ruby.rb', '.')
    end
```

there's also an `scp.upload`

Answer (score 15):

The [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/) library includes [Net::SCP](http://net-ssh.github.com/scp/v1/api/index.html), so you should start looking there.

From the Net::SCP docs:

```
  require 'net/scp'

  # upload a file to a remote server
  Net::SCP.upload!("remote.host.com", "username",
    "/local/path", "/remote/path",
    :password => "password")

  # download a file from a remote server
  Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username",
    "/remote/path", "/local/path",
    :password => password)

  # download a file to an in-memory buffer
  data = Net::SCP::download!("remote.host.com", "username", "/remote/path")
```

Comment: You'll need to modify the samples to fit your situation. The sample code isn't handing you fish to eat, it's showing you the appropriate things to use to catch your own fish.

Comment: Hi Tin, when I run the script it shows NoMethod error..what does that mean??.....this is my script..require net/scp

Comment: This is a great answer but how would I do it if I wanted to use a wildcard or regex to grab multiple files like file1 file2 file3. I tried /file*  in the remote path but it is looking for a file named file*. When I scp i know i can add quotes like this scp "1.1.1.1:/file*" /localDirectory.

Comment: @NickD: I think scp is the wrong tool if you want wildcards or regex. scp wants a path which it can recursively retrieve or an individual file. Perhaps sftp or something with more capability would help, or use a ssh session to find the files, then scp them individually..