# Ruby NET::SCP - how to dowload a file with PubkeyAuthentication=no option

Tags: ruby, ssh, scp

I tried to perform an scp by Ruby with this solution: [How do I transfer files using SSH and SCP using Ruby calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644110/how-do-i-transfer-files-using-ssh-and-scp-using-ruby-calls)

But when I execute, it prints:

```
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa:
```

But the host is a key-less server, I want to remove this "Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa:" question.

If I do in linux command line:

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.org
```

It works

I think I can pass the equivalent option to NET::SSH, but how I do that?
Sorry, I am new to ruby and I am not finding any option like this

I appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: could you add the key-value pair `PubkeyAuthentication=no` into **~/.ssh/config** for the specific host? and try to use `PreferredAuthentications` key instead of `PubkeyAuthentication`

Comment: You mean, add PubkeyAuthentication=no into ~/.ssh/config in the server side? It does not work. I tried to add it in the client but it didn't work either, I thought that maybe ruby executes in another user, but I add it in /etc/ssh/ssh_config and it didn't work either

Comment: No, add to cleint side, for the specific host, and not the `PubkeyAuthentication=no`, but `PreferredAuthentications=hostbased,keyboard-interactive,password`