# ruby on rails3 retrieve files from a remote server and make it available for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some files on a remote server in a directory such as:

```
171.XX.XX.XXX/test/data/file1.zip
171.XX.XX.XXX/test/data/file2.zip
```

So in my web application, when a user goes to page (eg. `www.mysite.com/downloads`) I want to retrieve some files from the remote server and make it available for the user to download.

So basically, the webpage would like

```
file1.zip
file2.zip
```

And when the user clicks on one, it downloads the remote files onto his local computer.

What is the best way to accomplish this on Ruby on Rails?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments it would make sense to pass through the server rather a direct link to the remote server.

EDIT2: Does 'open-uri' work with non http urls?

when i tried

```
url_file_path = open('172XX.XX7/test/data/my_file.zip').read
send_data url_file_path, filename: test.zip, type: 'application/octet-stream'
```

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you don't want to link directly to the remote file? You want it to pass through your server instead?

Comment: @substantial, you are correct. I should have mentioned that in my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to "download" the remote file first. with something like this in your controller

your_controller.rb

```
def download
  send_data remote_file(params[:url]), type: 'application/octet-stream'
end

private
def remote_file(url)
  open(url).read
end
```

you might need to

```
require 'open-uri'
```

normally u do this at top of of your controller

now you can define a route

```
get 'download' => 'your_controller#download', as: :download
```

now you can use in frontend

```
= link_to 'Download file1.zip', download_path(url: 'http://171.XX.XX.XXX/test/data/file1.zip')
```

Comment: thanks @marvwhere, I keep getting this error 'Errno::ENOENT', "No such file or directory". Is it because the remote server cannot be accessed through 'http'?

Comment: yeah thats true, looks like i missed the "none http" part. so u only have pure ssh? check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644110/how-do-i-transfer-files-using-ssh-and-scp-using-ruby-calls